# how to write a for loop in more compact way in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to make this code more compact...is there a way to do it

```
for line in  Qlines: #a loop that will read each line and store each given item in this case students and their marks to be stored in their given variables mentioned above
    eneq = line.split(';', 1) #splits the each line from the semicolon ";" 
    students.append(eneq[0]) #for each index 0 every line which would students names there will stored in a list format in the [] we created above and store in student variable and same thing applied to variable marks
    marks.append(eneq[1]) #for each index 1 every line which would be marks of students there are stored in variable marks
```

Comment: Why? This code is fine. Maybe do something like `student, mark = eneq = line.split(';', 1)` to make it more readable. That would improve it. Making it more compact doesn't help anything

Comment: Not to mention that code golf is technically off topic here

Comment: Do `students` and `marks` contain anything before this code? Or is this supposed to create them from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a list of pairs and then transpose it using the `zip(*x)` idiom:

```
students, marks = zip(*(line.split(';', 1) for line in Qlines))
```

This leaves `students` and `marks` as tuples. If you absolutely need lists, you can convert them manually:

```
students = list(students)
marks = list(marks)
```

Alternatively, you can do it as part of the original one-liner:

```
students, marks = map(list, zip(*(line.split(';', 1) for line in Qlines)))
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help you.
It is a more compact way of implementing. But note that compactness might make it harder to read and also more error prone. This way of coding is also inefficient because it iterates over the list twice.
But feel free to try and know different ways of coding in python.

```
students, marks = [ line.split(';', 1)[0] for line in Qlines ], [ line.split(';', 1)[1] for line in Qlines ]
```

Comment: Also, this iterates over `Qlines` more than once, so it is technically not equivalent, and won't handle iterators correctly (e.g. a file object)

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. But I though that it is the only way I know to do it in less lines of code. It is not efficient.

Comment: Sure, and I didn't downvote btw, just thought you should point that out because it is technically not equivalent

Comment: The issue isn't really the efficiency, but that this will be **incorrect** if, say, `Qlines = open("example.csv")`

Comment: No Need to iterate over the data two times. It won't optimize the code.